# presentModalViewController detecting animation completion

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I noticed iOS 5 introduced extra parameters and ways to detect when a view controller's presentation animation is complete.

Is there any way to do this in earlier versions, such as iOS 4.x?

I have used `presentModalViewController` to present the controller and I noticed that you can't call the dismiss method unless the animation has completed.

So how can I detect when the animation is complete so I can then dismiss it?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would the value be of presenting then immediately dismissing a modal view controller?

Comment: Oh... I present a Please Wait screen and do some network request which can take a minute or so.  If there is an error with the connection, sometimes its detected before the animation completes. If i dismiss it then, it just seems to ignore the command.

Comment: If you only want to show them that you're doing something while a long-running process completes, like fetching some data from the web, try using [`SVprogressHUD`](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD). It will disable the interface and show a `UIActivityIndicator`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried dismissing a modally presented VC, on viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear.  No dice on the first two, but the dismiss works in viewDidAppear.  (Kind of makes sense that that would get called after the animations are done).

And, you probably know this already, but in case you don't:  you don't have to dismiss the modally presented VC from the VC that presented it.  Your "wait for the network" VC can check the connection state in viewDidAppear, and dismiss itself if the connection is finished.

Comment: Awesome... thanks for that.  Hope it helps a lot more people too.  I'll try to update the post with my coded solution later.

Answer (score 0):

There's no exact way to do this - the best you can hope for is using the `viewDidDisappear:` from the presenting view controller. Make sure to use an boolean instance variable to determine if you're disappearing because the modal view controller is presenting, or some other reason.

Honestly, if you're building new software, I sternly encourage you to target iOS 5 and higher. The overwhelming majority of people have upgraded, and the rest will within a few months; there's simply no reason to support iOS 4 for new projects.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a try.  I guess I could also send a message back from the modal once it had loaded.  Any idea which of the "viewWillAppear" and "viewDidLoad" blocks or something else which would trigger only *after* the animation completes ??

Comment: Thats a really good question - Apple's documentation on the [View Controller Life Cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH10-SW1) is very comprehensive. I would suggest reading over Table 4-1 to get an idea of what logic to put in which methods. If you're using xib's instead of storyboard, that's fine, this guide still applies.

Answer (score 0):

Is it just a thing that says "wait, while i make a network request" ?  Maybe you could use a view for that (full sized attached to the keyWindow) instead of a whole view controller.  The vc launching the network request can present the view and remove it with any animation you like.  I have a class that does this.  Let me know if you want to try and I'll paste it in.

Comment: I should mention, it's OS5 code, so you'd have to add in manual garbage collection.

Comment: Yes, I agree that's an ok workaround, just a bit more work and code, and was just wondering if there was an answer to the specific question, for mine and others benefit.  Thanks.